# Synonym relationship between azure-documentdb and azure-cosmosdb should be reversed

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I think that the synonym relationship between [azure-documentdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-documentdb) and [azure-cosmosdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb) is the wrong way around.

The current direction of the relationship probably came about because first we had [azure-documentdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-documentdb), which then grew in to [azure-cosmosdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb).

But DocumentDB is now just one API of four which you can use to access CosmosDB.

APIS: MongoDB, DocumentDB, Gremlin (GraphAPI), Azure Tables

So if I asked a question about using the GraphAPI for CosmosDB, and tagged it with [azure-cosmosdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb), it'd end up as tagged with [azure-documentdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-documentdb) which is the wrong API.

Comment: This is correct.  For reference, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/dear-documentdb-customers-welcome-to-azure-cosmos-db/?cdn=disable and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos_DB

Comment: That wikipedia entry is incorrect and should be edited.

Comment: I'm not sure why Community started bumping this question with an old answer, but currently this has been done with [tag:azure-cosmosdb] being the main tag and [tag:azure-documentdb] being the synonym.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there should be no synonym whatsoever between these two.  CosmosDB is the family of data stores, and does not exist as an individual product.  For a brief window in time it seems as though they were simply going to rename DocumentDB to CosmosDB but they have moved past that.

Take a look at the [CosmosDB Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/) to see how Microsoft is currently framing this set of products.

To be aligned with the way the product is set up, the tags need to be as follows:

- azure-cosmosdb-documentdb
- azure-cosmosdb-mongodb
- azure-cosmosdb-graph
- azure-cosmosdb-table
- azure-cosmosdb-cassandra

There should be no 'azure-cosmosdb' as there is no one product that would be accurately described by this tag.